# getElementById() in for loop to retrieve input values

Tags: javascript, html, loops, getelementbyid

In a `for` loop, I am using `getElementById()` to retrieve several input values in javascript.

First I made a bunch of input boxes and set the different `id's` using a `for` loop.
Now I'm using a second `for` loop to reference those `id's` and retrieve their input values.

### Code:

```
for (i=0;i<products.length;i++){
    var display;
    display ="<input type='number' id="+products[i][0]+" onchange=myFunction()>";
    document.write(display);
}


document.write("<p id=demo></p>");

function myFunction() {
    var totalVeg=0;

    for (j=0;j<products.length;j++){
        amount = document.getElementById(products[j][0]).value;
        totalVeg += amount;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + totalVeg;

}
</script>
```

Specifically I'm having trouble with this part:

```
amount = document.getElementById(products[j][0]).value;
```

If I reference a specific input, like `products[0][0]`, the value will be found. It is only when I try to reference an `id` using the `"j"` variable then the code stops working.

I've read through some of the other questions and answers on here but none are exactly what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? null?

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/jwejrssw/). However, it concatenates the values because they are strings, you should convert them to numbers in order to sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
       var products = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
       for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        var display;
        display ="<input type='number' id='"+products[i]+"'onchange=myFunction(this.id)>";
document.write(display);
         }


        document.write("<p id=demo></p>");
          var totalVeg=0;
          function myFunction(_this) {
          amount = parseInt(document.getElementById(_this).value);
          totalVeg += amount;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + totalVeg;
         }
      </script>
```

You can take it as a reference. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

seem you don't have the quote around the id  andbthen the id is not properly defined try this way

```
for (i=0;i<products.length;i++){
  var display;
  display ="<input type='number' id='"+products[i][0]+"'   onchange=myFunction()>";
  document.write(display);
}
```